# How to avoid the hidden fileds form submit?

Tags: php, html, ajax

I have a html form with the disaply:none elements, so when i submit the form it post also the hidden fields elements, how to avoid the those things?

Comment: why you add hiddens on form if don't want to use?

Comment: are you submitting for via AJAX??

Comment: if you don't want to submit them with form submission then why you are using hidden values???

Comment: if fields are present inside the form then the fields will be submitted. you can just unset them if not required depending on the condition but cant stop them from submitting if they are present inside the form.

Comment: i've a form to apply a leave, so when user choose a single day leave it shows the duration( select filed with options morning and afternoon) and when select a couple of days it hides the duration fileds and show the partial day field( with options start day,end day,both), so i've used display:none

Comment: In your PHP code, when you set `display:none`, simply also set the name to nothing. That would make it not submit a value when the user hits that submit button.

Comment: i'm using ajax to submit a form,so it's not redirect right? so when the user select single day leave first also selected afternoon duration and then suddenly he changed the plan and apply for a couple of day's leave with the partial day options , so here duration has a afternoon value and partial filed also have value.

Comment: Two options: 1) Publish your PHP code or 2) run a search on StackOverflow. You'll get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `display: none`, or any CSS setting for that matter, does not affect the functionality of a hidden input field. To prevent an `<input type=hidden ...>` element from submitting (more exactly: from giving contribution to the form data set when the form is submitted), you can

- remove the element or
- set the `disabled` attribute on it (or set the `disabled` property of the element node to `true` with JavaScript)